# Catalog Search Results page - sort by price not working

Tags: search, magento-2.2.5, sort

Steps to reproduce:

1. Search for a term and the results are displayed by default sorted by
   Relevance.
2. Change the sort by parameter to Price and change the sort to ascending order.
3. Results are not sorted in the ascending order.

Error in console:

> loader.js:210 Expected to start loader but did not find one in the dom

Looks like the query string parameter **product_list_dir** is missing. when I manually add it in the URL, it sorts fine.

Comment: Can you please specify magento version?

Comment: Magento version 2.2.5